# Typing a nullable callback variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to simplify the declaration of `resolve` variable in the TypeScript code below, without sacrificing type safety? I'm new to TypeScript, please bear with me.

The goal is to save the promise resolver callback, passed to to the executor function, so it can be invoked later outside it. What I've come up with is `let resolve: ((v: number) => void) | null = null`. Try it in [the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABLAtgUziKAKFBnALkTBBQCM0AnASiIAVK4UY80AeE8qgPkQG8AUIkQB6EYjwBDAG5pkACzkAHRs1YByPIkpo8cADazKyOIgqIYYaXADWaACaJ9kqFSFO0UbboOyi2bGkiTgoaRABeXmsYe2pEAB9iEH19CKSUgG5RcTZwvPcIBDwvJTSwNAB3RAYmFnYQnmxjSO89Qzlw7WoMgQKir2LJSi9OpSpgOEoUSUg0ADowOArsbvdWKAAVGHRMHBWI3h022QBCbDHKCamZiHnF5biAWgkoIahqABpEfFXhHSgQJQkEoegBfXqSPAAT0giFAkFgCG+kks+0EwkKYGKTkkSlYaUkFRRXlQGCw2AATAAGGm-RCSfRUHDOPFoVbggTTVHUOYQFwQeTYDq8BlMoVzdB4KQAczZ3SAA):

```
function timeout(ms: number): Promise<number> {
  // save the promise's resolver to be invoked later
  let resolve: ((v: number) => void) | null = null; // <===
  const p = new Promise<number>(r => resolve = r);

  const start = performance.now();
  setTimeout(() => resolve!(performance.now() - start), ms);
  return p;
}
```

If I don't make it a union type with `null`, TypeScript will legitly complain that `resolve` might be uninitialized when I invoke it later: `setTimeout(() => resolve(...), ms)`. Is there a more concise way to do this, without introducing `any` or TypeScript errors?

To clarify, the above example is a bit contrived, it could be easily simplified like this:

```
function timeout(ms: number): Promise<number> {
    const start = performance.now();
    return new Promise<number>(r => 
        setTimeout(() => r(performance.now() - start)));
}
```

The question is however about TypeScript syntax. The actual code does need to save the promise's `resolve` and `reject` callbacks to implement [the `Deferred` pattern](https://dev.to/noseratio/a-few-handy-javascript-tricks-an9#thenables).

Comment: At some point I had it [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.1.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABLAtgUziKAKFBnALkTBBQCM0AnASiIAVK4UY80AeE8qgPkQG8AUIkQB6EYjwBDAG5pkACzkAHRs1YByPIkpo8cADazKyOIgqIYYaXADWaACaJ9kqFSFO0UbboOyi2bGkiTgoaRABeXmsYe2pEAB9iEH19CKSUgG5EdwgEPC8lNLA0AHdEBiYWdhCebGNI7z1DOXDtagz3MUQAOl73HSbZAEJsABYAJnb+zxBKJCUOgF8BIA), where | null` and `!` were required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it more concise is to remove the `null`s and not assign anything to `resolve` at first:

```
function timeout(ms: number): Promise<number> {
    let resolve: (v: number) => void;
    const p = new Promise<number>(r => resolve = r);

    const start = performance.now();
    setTimeout(() => resolve(performance.now() - start), ms);
    return p;
}
```

It may look a bit odd, but this does happen to work with any `!` assertion.

If you happen to be able to return the Promise immediately, you could slim it down to

```
function timeout(ms: number) {
    let resolve: (v: number) => void;
    return new Promise<number>(r => {
        resolve = r;
        const start = performance.now();
        setTimeout(() => resolve(performance.now() - start), ms);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is where I got also, but I'm not sure why the compiler is happy about that either.  If you change `p`'s definition to `const p = new Promise<number>(r => void 0);` there is no compiler error but you'll get runtime errors about `resolve` not being a function.  I think this is a limitation about callbacks and control flow analysis (like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  Personally I'd rather do it the original way and use the `!` so there's some indication that I know something is amiss here

Comment: Looks like it's #9998 (at least https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22468 indicates that) so it's just another situation where the compiler just hopes for the best when dealing with closed-over values in a callback that isn't immediately invoked inline.

Comment: Interesting! **I swear I was getting a warning about nullability when I started**, so I had to union and initialized it with `null`, then use `!`. But I can't repro that warning anymore even with my own Playground snippet! Is there a TS flag or anything I might have turned on/off somehow?

Comment: I see now, at some point I had it [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.2.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABLAtgUziKAKFBnALkTBBQCM0AnASiIAVK4UY80AeE8qgPkQG8AUIkQB6EYjwBDAG5pkACzkAHRs1YByPIkpo8cADazKyOIgqIYYaXADWaACaJ9kqFSFO0UbboOyi2bGkiTgoaRABeXmsYe2pEAB9iEH19CKSUgG5EdwgEPC8lNLA0AHdEBiYWdhCebGNI7z1DOXDtagz3HSbZAEJsABYAJnbOzxBKJCUOgF8BIA), where the `| null` and `!` is required. Is there a shorter version for this? cc @jcalz

Comment: @noseratio You could leave off the `: Promise<number>` in the return type if you wanted, TS can infer it automatically. Other than that, if you don't want to go the route in the answer without initial assignment, I don't think so, but the code looks pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, it helps. I'm coming to TS with rather solid C# and JavaScript background but I feel I might be struggling a bit with some TS concepts, including `| null` for nullability. One other thing is with [how TS treats classes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42698).